# Beautiful find_all does not return values randomly

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to get some information from a website and therefor I go to its page and get all the links which contain a certain string in the link. 
Then I loop through the links and want to get the information from the link webpages. however sometimes BeautifullSoup function doesnt return values.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.website.com/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('a')

#creating the list for all links found 
links = []

for result in results:
    if  "speciallink" in result['href']:
        href = 'https://www.website.com'+result['href']
        links.append(href)

links = list(set(links))

for link in links:
        url = link
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
        txt = 'text1'
        results = soup.find_all("div",{'class':txt})
        try:
            date = results[0].string
        except IndexError:
            print("error")
```

But when I use the loop again only with the url which apparently has no value in it it then returns values most of the time but sometimes not:

```
for link in links:
        url = 'https://www.website.com/page_with_error/'
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
        txt = 'text1'
        results = soup.find_all("div",{'class':txt})
        try:
            date = results[0].string
        except IndexError:
            print("error")
```

It is a static website though. Is it maybe because the website is not finished loading?

**[temporarily Solution]**

I made a small fix which helps solving this problem but I think its not a nice solution. I just use a while loop to get the needed info:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.website.com/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('a')

#creating the list for all links found 
links = []
for link in links:
        url = 'https://www.website.com/page_with_error/'
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
        txt = 'text1'
        results = soup.find_all("div",{'class':txt})
        error =0
#new- i added this
        while(len(results) == 0 ):
                error = error +1
                r = requests.get(url)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
                txt = 'text1'
                results = soup.find_all("div",{'class':txt})
                if(error>10000):
                        print("got to break that")
                            break
# new-over
        try:
            date = results[0].string
        except IndexError:
            print("error")
```

Comment: rate limiting maybe? try checking the whole content you get after `requests.get`. If it's `403 Forbidden` or something like that, it means you need to slow down a little

Comment: how do I slow down?

Comment: do the status codes remain the same through out?

Comment: Include some `time.sleep(5)` for example to suspend the execution of your script. It will slow down the requests

Comment: @QHarr what exactly do you mean by status code?

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/    status_code

Comment: ok thank you. yes it stays the same